# Using this keyword to access public variable in Javascript Module Pattern

Tags: javascript, global-variables

I've been looking at how to not use Global Variables http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2007/06/12/module-pattern/

What I'm not getting is how to use 'this' to access a public variable within my returned object.

```
console.log(this.myPublicProperty);
```

But if I use:

```
console.log(MYAPP.myProject.myModule.myPublicProperty);
```

I'll see the variable in the log.

I get 'undefined' when I try and access that public variable. 
Am I missing something that's not shown in the example code?

Thanks!

```
var MYAPP = {};
MYAPP.myProject = {};
MYAPP.myProject.myModule = function () {

    //"private" variables:
    var myPrivateVar = "I can be accessed only from within MYAPP.myProject.myModule.";

    //"private" method:
    var myPrivateMethod = function () {
        console.log("I can be accessed only from within MYAPP.myProject.myModule");
    }

    return  {
        myPublicProperty: "I'm accessible as MYAPP.myProject.myModule.myPublicProperty.",
        myPublicMethod: function () {
            console.log("I'm accessible as MYAPP.myProject.myModule.myPublicMethod.");

            //Within myProject, I can access "private" vars and methods:
            console.log(myPrivateVar);
            console.log(myPrivateMethod());

            //The native scope of myPublicMethod is myProject; we can
            //access public members using "this":
            console.log(this.myPublicProperty);
        }
    };
}(); // the parens here cause the anonymous function to execute and return
```

Comment: How and when are you trying to access your public property?  Can you show some code.

Comment: *The native scope of `myPublicMethod` is `myProject`*: No, it's `MYAPP.myProject.myModule`, if you can even say this. It depends on how `myPublicMethod` is called.

Comment: @Zoidberg I don't really have anything I'm doing yet, just trying to understand how it works. Except for the first 2 lines I lifted the code from the YUI blog entry, just changed YAHOO to MYAPP and I'm testing in TextMate and Chrome.

Comment: Maybe it's because I used console.log where the blog entry has YAHOO.log? I haven't tried to use this.myPublicProperty inside the object, but I'll try that instead of trying to print to the log. I was feeling good about understanding this until I got to that last bit about //access public members using "this":

Comment: `console.log(myPrivateMethod())` logs `undefined` because the `myPrivateMethod` logs something and then implicitly *returns* `undefined` (because it does not return anything). So that log will evaluate to `console.log(undefined)`. The last `console.log` with `this.myPublicProperty` has no problems; at least I cannot reproduce any issues with `this`.

Comment: @pimvdb I think I see it now. I was also trying to use the console to invoke the method to begin with. When I just use MYAPP.myProject.myModule.myPublicMethod(); the this.myPublicProperty works fine and I see the undefined for console.log(myPrivateMethod()); Thanks guys!! I think it's time to try and put some of this new learning to practice.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like using `this` and dynamic binding to access a public variable, since it can break if I pass one of my functions as a callback or something like that. I prefer to have the references in my modules be static:

```
var M = { //explicit name
    f1: function(){ return M.f2(); },
    f2: function(){ }
};

return M;
```